# How to make multiple selection steps to show a link based on selected options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to create order page based on selections.
I have 4 variations of product. User first need to select country and then product type.

There needs to be steps.
Step 1: User should select Country Option (1 or 2)
Step 2: User should select Product Type (A or B)

So depending on this selections "Buy Now" link need to be change based on selection. Like 1&A link, or 2&A link, or 1&B link.

Is it possible to do this with bootstrap or jquery?

Comment: Yes its possible to do with JQuery and if your selection is being stored on database, you can use ajax to call php commands as well.

Comment: it is not stored on database. there will be 4 button with 4 different add to cart option. depending on selections user made, button will appear on last step.

Comment: Use `change()` for dropdown. Based on value, display that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `<select>`, you can try to use *jQuery* method *change()*.

The idea is, when a certain value is selected, then we do this. And if another is selected, then we do that.

I'll leave comments in the code so you know what each line is doing.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  // This is when this select is selected, it opens the country select.
  $('#country').on('change',function(){
    $("#other").css("display","block");
  });



  // First, lets check if the dropdown has an onChange that took place
  $('#other').on('change',function(){
  
    // Store the value of the selected option into a variable
   var selectedCountry = $("#other option:selected").val();
    
    // If that option is 1, then we make the button block so it appears, we change the href link to your desired URL as well as change the text for that button. You can remove whichever feature you don't want.
    if(selectedCountry==1) {
      $("#cart").css("display","block");
      $("#cart").attr("href", "#");
      $("#cart").html('Add To Cart - Singapore');
   } 
    
    // Use else if if the option is 2, then do the following as mentioned above.
    else if(selectedCountry==2) {
     $("#cart").css("display","block");
      $("#cart").attr("href", "#");
      $("#cart").html('Add To Cart - USA');
    } else {
      // If its not 1 or 2, then make button disappear again , so that when someone clicks on an option and deciddes to go back to default Please select option, the add to cart will disappear.
      $("#cart").css("display","none");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#cart {
  display: none;
}

#other {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Singapore</option>
  <option value="2">USA</option>
</select>

<select id="other">
 <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<button id="cart"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you @Gosi it works great but can you also show me how to improve it like this:
When you select "Country 1" it shows another "select dropdown" and after you select second dropdown menu, add to cart button appears.

Comment: Ok edited my answer, if its correct, please mark it correct.